# How can I use a regex subpattern with a named group in Python?

Tags: python, regex, perl

I am translating a regex-heavy script from Perl to Python and I have a problem with regex subpatterns.

In Perl, if I write the following works as expected, i.e. the string "OK" is written. I have never given it much thought, but it just looks like Perl knows that those are different groups although they have the same name.

```
my $ident  = qr{ (?<guill> ['"`]? ) [a-zA-Z_] \w* \g{guill} }x;
my $idents = qr{ (?: $ident \s* , \s* )* $ident }x;
my $test   =  q{'test', "test"};

if ($test =~ $idents) {
    say 'OK';
}
```

I have found no way to interpolate a subpattern inside a pattern in Python besides concetenating strings before they are compiled as regex patterns, so I translated my Perl code as:

```
ident  = r"(?P<guill> ['\"`]? ) [a-zA-Z_] \w* (P=guill)"
idents = r"(?: " + ident + r" \s* , \s* )* " + ident
test   = "'test', \"test\""

if re.match( idents, test, re.VERBOSE ):
    print "OK"
```

Unsurprisingly, that does not even compile, as Python complains about the "redefinition of group name 'guill' as group 3". I tried the Perlish way and `re.compile`'d `ident`, but then it refused to concatenate a string with a pattern object.

What would be the Pythonish way of achieving this?

Comment: Python regexes have only backreference but can't use subpatterns. And AFIK you can't define twice the same named group.

Comment: However you can install the module "regex" instead of "re", that has more features.

Comment: Thank you, I just followed your suggestion. The new package has some interesting features, but subpatterns unfortunately don't seem to be among them.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, The Perl code posted above does not use any subpatterns, just named captures. `qr{ (?: (?^x: (?<guill> ['"\`]? ) [a-zA-Z_] \w* \g{guill} ) \s* , \s* )* (?^x: (?<guill> ['"\`]? ) [a-zA-Z_] \w* \g{guill} ) }x` would be equivalent.

Comment: Re "I have found no way to interpolate a subpattern inside a pattern in Python besides concetenating strings", which is what your Perl code does too.

Comment: @ikegami, That does create a subpattern in the sense that Perl surrounds the interpolated pattern with `(?:)`. I thought this somehow had a special semantics for Perl which made it work, but I have tested and realised that you are right, doing the interpolation by hand and without `(?:)` gives the same result. Which simplifies the question to: How can I use a group name many times in Python with the same semantics as in Perl?

Comment: @ikegami: I was thinking about something like that (in oniguruma syntax): `((?<guill>...\g{guill})) \s* , \s* )* \g<1>` where `\g<1>` is the first subpattern and avoid to rewrite the begining of the pattern. But you can't do that in Python.

Comment: Re: "That does create a subpattern in the sense that Perl surrounds the interpolated pattern with `(?:)`", If that's true, then your Python code has subpatterns too. Re "Which simplifies the question to: How can I use a group name many times", they're called named captures. But you've apparently found out you can't, so that's not really the question either.

Comment: @ikegami, I do suppose there is a way of achieving the desired result without having to write two different versions of `ident` thereabove (a few dozens in the actual script I'm translating)...

Comment: 1. I don't know Python. 2. What two versions?

Comment: @ikegami, Two versions with differently named groups. But nevermind, as far as inelegant solutions go, the one you suggest below is nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same as @ikegami's answer, but without the `identN` names (usually an indication that a list is a better choice), and a more Pythonic `'|'.join`:

```
subidents = [
    r"[a-zA-Z_] \w*",
    r"'[a-zA-Z_] \w* '",
    r"\"[a-zA-Z_] \w* \"",
    r"`[a-zA-Z_] \w* `",
    ]
ident = "(?:%s)" % '|'.join(subidents)
```

Now you can just extend your list of subidents as more crop up.

Pro tip: add a trailing comma after the last list item when you are likely to add more items later - cuts down on extraneous change lines when comparing versions.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using true regular expressions.

```
ident0 = r"[a-zA-Z_] \w*"
ident1 = r"' [a-zA-Z_] \w* '"
ident2 = r"\" [a-zA-Z_] \w* \""
ident3 = r"` [a-zA-Z_] \w* `"
ident  = "(?:" + ident0 + "|" + ident1 + "|" + ident2 + "|" + ident3 + ")"
```

Comment: Thank you. I would have hoped a language hailed as so much more elegant than Perl would have had a cleaner solution though...